# How to disable webform Results tab in webform without uncheked Access all webform results?

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm using D7, i like to hide web form result tab, i try with tab tamer module,but it doesn't work i still got access to submission results,when i unchecked Bypass views access control and Access all webform results permissions, results tab become disable but in this case i couldn't change my webform workflow submissions anymore. Could any one suggest me an idea how to disable result tab without disabling the possibility to change my webform worflow state

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Webform access callback, [`webform_results_access()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21webform%21webform.module/function/webform_results_access/7), for the submissions tab is structured so evoking the built its hook [`hook_webform_results_access()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21webform%21webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_results_access/7) can't override *Access all webform results* permissions check.

However, a custom module could override the tab's access callback with your own custom logic:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%webform_menu/webform-results']['access callback'] = 'MYMODULE_webform_results_access';
}
function MYMODULE_webform_results_access() {
  $result = FALSE;
  // @TODO: Add access logic
  return $result;
}
```